# How to limit the number of items per table row?

Tags: css, html

Table shows large number of items per row so it goes beyond screen. I tried to add CSS style to modify table width but didn't work.

I thought about putting break line after definite number(maybe using JQuery) of items while I create each row in iterative mode. Is there any way to define number of items created dynamically in each table row?

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean by `items`?

Comment: Depends how you are creating them dynamically. It would be a good idea to edit your question and add your code to a code snippet.

Comment: Are you attempting to avoid horizontal scroll? Make it responsive or only span 100% of viewport? Does user need to see all columns of data?

Comment: It depends on your desired implementation. You could use [`:nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-child) to limit the rows shown. Also, you could add indices using JavaScript and hide rows away on user interaction.

Comment: I use table data <td> to show data set

Comment: `@foreach (var item in Model)
    {
          <tr>
            <td>
              @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.registeredequipmentcount)
            </td>
         </tr>
    }`

Comment: Question of Alexander Staroselsky still remain? Especially last one.

Comment: Yes. definitely. i want to avoid horizontal scroll! I'm expecting repsonsive view as browser size changes. Yes the user needs to see all columns at once.

Answer (score 1):

You must modify table header width, the child row/td will inherit from that size like this :

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="20%">Column 1</th>
            <th width="20%">Column 2</th>
            <th width="20%">Column 3</th>
            <th width="20%">Column 4</th>
            <th width="20%">Column 5</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Data column 1</td>
            <td>Data column 2</td>
            <td>Data column 3</td>
            <td>Data column 4</td>
            <td>Data column 5</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Note: you must have the same number of columns in both `<thead>` and `<tbody>`